# Setting property value in Groovy using two different setters

Tags: groovy

I would like to allow user to set a `BigDecimal` property in my class using both `BigDecimal` and `String` (for backward compatibility reasons).

```
extension.timeoutFactor = 1.81
extension.timeoutFactor = "2.12"
```

It tried to use two setter with different parameter types:

```
class PitestPluginExtension {
    BigDecimal timeoutFactor

    void setTimeoutFactor(BigDecimal timeoutFactor) {
        this.timeoutFactor = timeoutFactor
    }

    @Deprecated
    void setTimeoutFactor(String timeoutFactor) {
        //display deprecation warning
        this.timeoutFactor = timeoutFactor.toBigDecimal()
    }
}
```

but Groovy fails with:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object
    '2.12' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.math.BigDecimal'
```

If the setters are called directly everything work fine, but this is a [Gradle plugin](http://gradle-pitest-plugin.solidsoft.info/) and people used to use property assignments.

Is it possible to tell Groovy (1.8.6) to use different input types on a property assignment (preferably without using Groovy meta programming)?

Comment: Why without metaprogramming?

Comment: @WillP, the extension class is managed by Gradle (see configuration [example](https://github.com/szpak/gradle-pitest-plugin#plugin-configuration)) and there could be (potentially) some issues with the internal Gradle magic performed on this class. Therefore I would prefer a clear solution using "standard" approach (like setters with different parameters types - which unfortunately doesn't work). Nevertheless if it would be not "possible" in Groovy the (working) solution with meta programming would be also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution (hinted by @Don's answer!) seems to work because `1.21` as `BigDecimal` is losslessly converted to `String` and used in the setter. Later it can be get as `BigDecimal`.

```
class PitestPluginExtension {
    BigDecimal timeoutFactor

    void setTimeoutFactor(String timeoutFactor) {
        this.timeoutFactor = new BigDecimal(timeoutFactor)
    }
}

def extension = new PitestPluginExtension()
extension.timeoutFactor = "1.81"
assert extension.timeoutFactor == 1.81
extension.timeoutFactor = 1.21
assert extension.timeoutFactor == 1.21
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.math.*

class PitestPluginExtension {
    private BigDecimal timeoutFactor

    void setTimeoutFactor(timeoutFactor) {
        this.timeoutFactor = new BigDecimal(timeoutFactor)
    }

    def getTimeoutFactor() {
        this.timeoutFactor
    }
}

// ignore differences due to precision errors
void compareImprecisely(BigDecimal expected, BigDecimal actual) {
    BigDecimal roundedExpected = Math.round(expected * 100) / 100
    BigDecimal roundedActual = Math.round(actual * 100) / 100
    assert roundedExpected == roundedActual
}

def ppe = new PitestPluginExtension()

def expected = new BigDecimal('1.11')

// test assigning a string
ppe.timeoutFactor = '1.11'
compareImprecisely expected, ppe.timeoutFactor

// test assigning a BigDecimal
ppe.timeoutFactor = 1.11
compareImprecisely expected, ppe.timeoutFactor
```

Comment: Nice trick, thanks for your answer. The thing I don't like it that `new BigDecimal(1.11)` executes `BigDecimal(double val)` while normally `1.11.class == java.math.BigDecimal`. This forces me to round the value before passing it on. Nevertheless your idea hinted me an another [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23094302/313516).